# Допустимо ли сочетание слов "достаточно обычно /-ен,  /--на ?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Добрый день!
Допустимо ли написать в качестве замены словосочетанию "часто встречается",  "широко распространено" словосочетание "достаточно обычно"?
Что-нибудь вроде: В настоящее время встретить человека, пользующегося мобильным телефоном достаточно обычно.  Или: В настоящее  время наличие дома компьютера  достаточно обычно.

Comment: @Mihal, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Лучше сказать "вполне обычно" или "весьма обычно". "Достаточно" - характеристика меры (достаточно часто - много раз в единицу времени; достаточно много для чего-то; достаточно для того, чтобы). Не всегда уловима граница между допустимостью употребления словосочетания с "достаточно", но здесь оно не очень хорошо воспринимается: "обычно" плохо поддаётся "измерениям", можно только придавать разную степень уверенности "обычности".

Answer (score 1):

ДОСТАТОЧНЫЙ -  1) Удовлетворяющий потребностям, необходимым условиям.  Он располагает достаточной суммой денег. Д 2) В должной мере обоснованный, веский; основательный. Достаточные основания для отказа.

Наречие, образованное от прилагательного "достаточный",  в своем основном значении не является наречием степени, но в словаре для него дается РАЗГОВОРНЫЙ вариант с таким значением (в значительной степени). Д. умён. За эти годы он д. постарел.

ПРИМЕРЫ

В моей нынешней школе всё достаточно обычно, белая блузка, черные брюки или юбка, ― вот весь дресс-код. Жизнь его начиналась достаточно обычно для юноши его положения. Все это было достаточно сложно, но и достаточно обычно.

Answer (score 1):

Достаточно обычно - так говорить нельзя. Налицо лексическая несочетаемость и неблагозвучие (дважды -чно).

**обы́чно**
I нареч. качеств.-обстоят. 
1.
Так, как всегда; привычно.
2.
Так, как все, ничем не выделяясь; заурядно.
II предик. 
1.
Оценочная характеристика ситуации, чьих-либо действий как являющихся привычными.
2.
Оценочная характеристика каких-либо качеств, чьих-либо действий как являющихся такими, как у всех.
*Толковый словарь Ефремовой. Т. Ф. Ефремова. 2000.*

Comment: Разговорная форма указана в словаре на "Грамота.ру".

Comment: Соглашусь с EkaterinaKas. Подобные повторения для слуха не благозвучны, поэтому слово "обычно" лучше сочетать с другим наречием, например, "довольно", либо, как у Alex_anderа: вполне, весьма.

Answer (score 1):

***"достаточно обычно"?***

Грамматически правильное сочетание.

Употреблялось и Визбором, и Искандером, и… (см. http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&spd=&text=lexgramm&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%E4%EE%F1%F2%E0%F2%EE%F7%ED%EE&gramm1=&sem1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&flags1=&m1=&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=%EE%E1%FB%F7%ED%FB%E9&gramm2=&sem2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&flags2=&m2= )

Но… Если, к примеру, во фразе *"Всё остальное в фильме **достаточно обычно** и просто"* меня ничего не напрягает, то в Ваших примерах чувствую какую-то неправильность.

И даже если убрать это *неблагозвучное* слово *(достаточно)* из Ваших примеров, превратив их в
*"В настоящее время встретить человека, пользующегося мобильным телефоном, обычно"* и *"В настоящее время наличие дома компьютера обычно",* лучше они от этого, по-моему, не станут.

Интересная статья о наступлении слова ***достаточно*** -- здесь:
https://books.google.ru/books?id=SR2kAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT150&dq=%22%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-+%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=9C3CVJmpBMSpygP54IKABQ&ved=0CC4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%22&f=false

Comment: Думаю, что у наречия "достаточно" в значении "очень, весьма" сочетаемость с прилагательными НЕПОЛНАЯ: можно сказать "достаточно хорошо", но не  стоит говорить "достаточно плохо". Это наречие имеет смысл тогда, когда накоплено определенное количество положительного или просто нужного свойства.

Answer (score 1):

Слово "обычно" выражает довольно высокую степень появления события; почти что "всегда". Оно равнозначно выражению "как правило". Да, мол, бывает что не встретишь человека с телефоном, но редко. Поэтому приувеличивать или приуменьшать эту степень уточнением "достаточно" бессмысленно. Я уж не говорю о благозвучности. Действительно, максимально упростим предложение: ...встретить человека с телефоном обычно. Можно. Но в какие ворота?